# Rails 3 & Colorbox Integration Problem

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, colorbox

I'm attempting to use [Colorbox](http://colorpowered.com/colorbox/) along with Rails 3 but I'm running into one problem. I'm doing something like the following:

```
<script type = "text/javascript">

   $(function() {

      $('a.modal').colorbox({});

   });

</scirpt>
```

The problem that I'm having is that when colorbox displays the content of requested page it's displaying the entire page (header, footer, content, etc), when all that I really want it the content. I'm not sure if this is something to do w/ Colorbox or something that I need to handle w/ Rails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like the requested page conforms to whatever default layout you're using for the rest of your app (usually application.html.erb).

If that is the case, it's not a ColorBox issue but rather a question of getting Rails to render your content using a different layout for the requested page.  You'll probably want a separate action in the controller that uses a custom layout to render the view rather than the default application.html.erb layout.

For example, let's say your ColorBox links currently invoke this action:

```
def show
  @foo = Foo.find(params[:id])
end
```

You would do something like this for the ColorBox action:

```
def colorbox
  @foo = Foo.find(params[:id])
  render :layout => "colorbox"
end
```

And create a colorbox.html.erb layout and corresponding routes entry.

Comment: That works but the only problem is that I would have to create a separate action for each method that I want a colorbox version of. Is there a way for Rails to detect if the request is coming from Colorbox & set the layout accordingly?

Comment: you could use the `respond_to do |format|` and set the layout on `format.js`

Comment: Are we talking about multiple actions in one controller, or multiple actions across various controllers?

Comment: Did you find a better solution?

Answer (score 0):

Although the accepted solution is correct for Rails in general when you don't want the layout to appear, it isn't the solution for the issue encountered. I've also attempted to implement [colorbox]:(https://github.com/jackmoore/colorbox) into a Rails 3.2 app. I stumbled upon the same issue, namely the modal window was showing the page on which the link was clicked.

Before, in the Rails view file (.html.erb):

```
<% content_for :head do %>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'colorbox' %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'jquery.colorbox' %>
  <%= javascript_tag do -%>
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $("a.modal").colorbox({});
    });
  <% end -%>
<% end %>

<% @photos.each do |photo| %>
  <%= link_to image_tag(photo.url(:thumb)), '#', :class => 'modal' %>
<% end %>
```

Essentially the application layout (application.html.erb layout) was being shown because the link was pointing to the current page '#' which utilizes the application.html.erb layout. The link should be an image path, not a Rails route (controller method):

```
<% @photos.each do |photo| %>
  <%= link_to image_tag(photo.url(:thumb)), photo.url, :class => 'group1' %>
<% end %>
```

Note: This solution is using methods specific to my setup using carrierwave for photo uploads and thumbnail creation. Here's a generic solution:

```
<p><a href="/images/image_1.jpg" class="modal">Image 1</a></p>
<p><a href="/images/image_2.jpg" class="modal">Image 2</a></p>
<p><a href="/images/image_3.jpg" class="modal">Image 3</a></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery-modal-rails gem provides a global filter to not render layout if request is an ajax one. You can use this idea [filter code](https://github.com/dei79/jquery-modal-rails/blob/e6884164026e07d9f78a5f1d63efe59f9ea54aa8/lib/jquery/modal/filters/ajax_request_filters.rb) to create similar effect for your colorbox integration. The code would be like this in ApplicationController.

```
  before_filter do |controller|
    (controller.action_has_layout = false) if controller.request.xhr?
  end
```